# How to load properties for Blueprint XML from database

Tags: java, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I need to load some properties for Blueprint XML from database. How to do this in Blueprint XML? I have struggled to find good examples for Blueprint. Is there something similar to Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd">
    <jaxrs:server id="restService" address="{{url.in}}">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref component-id="restSvc"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
</bean>
```

Comment: WHy not just in a simple config file? Databases are overkill and add a serious point of failure into the mix.

Comment: @Namphibian There are perhaps other applications that do not use Blueprint that need to access the same information contained in a configuration xml. It is better to provide a modular database that provides configuration data for *n* applications.

Comment: @JonathanKomar that is irrelevant in regards to the question. It is blueprint specific. You can share config files by mounting them on a network drive and Karaf(blueprint run time) has the ability to share them in the environment. Other places this might be different.